# Golang Printing 2-dimensional slices with struct include recursive pointers

Tags: go

struct user include struct parent pointer
struct oneUsers is struct user slices
struct twoUsers is struct oneUsers slices

twoUsers -> oneUsers -> user -> parent

I try to print twoUsers without any pointers value

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type parent struct {
    id int
}

type user struct {
    id     int
    name   string
    email  string
    parent *parent
}

func (u *user) String() string {
    if u == nil {
        return "nil"
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%#v", *u)
}

func (p *parent) String() string {
    if p == nil {
        return "nil"
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%#v", *p)
}

func (o *oneUsers) String() string {
    if o == nil {
        return "nil"
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%#v", *o)
}

type oneUsers []*user

type twoUsers []*oneUsers

func main() {
    var oneUser oneUsers
    p := parent{id: 6}
    oneUser = append(oneUser, &user{id: 1, name: "cooluser1", email: "cool.user1@gmail.com", parent: &p})
    oneUser = append(oneUser, &user{id: 2, name: "cooluser2", email: "cool.user2@gmail.com"})
    fmt.Printf("oneUser: %+v\n", oneUser)
    var twoUser twoUsers
    twoUser = append(twoUser, &oneUser)
    fmt.Printf("twoUser: %v\n", twoUser)
}
```

I try to add String() function in all of struct pointer, but print pointer value also
The print is

```bash
oneUser: [main.user{id:1, name:"cooluser1", email:"cool.user1@gmail.com", parent:(*main.parent)(0xc00001a120)} main.user{id:2, name:"cooluser2", email:"cool.user2@gmail.com", parent:(*main.parent)(nil)}]
twoUser: [main.oneUsers{(*main.user)(0xc000108150), (*main.user)(0xc000108180)}]
```

Comment: Can you explain more what is the problem? What did you expected to print?

Comment: every porinter print the Actual Values

Answer (score 0):

`twoUser` points to an array of `oneUser` pointers. So when you want to print `twoUser`, it just prints some pointers. If you want to print `oneUser` values inside `twoUser`, change this method `func (o *oneUsers) String() string` to something like that:

```
func (o *oneUsers) String() string {
    if o == nil {
        return "nil"
    }

    str := ""
    for _, user := range *o {
        if user == nil {
            return "nil"
        }
        str += fmt.Sprintf("%#v", *user)
    }
    return str
}
```

output:

```
twoUser: [main.user{id:1, name:"cooluser1", email:"cool.user1@gmail.com", parent:(*main.parent)(0xc00001c0d8)}main.user{id:2, name:"cooluser2", email:"cool.user2@gmail.com", parent:(*main.parent)(nil)}]
```